# Typescript: How to reference jquery-easyui library?

Tags: typescript, jquery-easyui

I'm new to typescript. I was trying to work with the [jquery-easyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/index.php) library which does  not have a d.ts definition file in the DefintelyTyped repo. I do not have the time (or skills) to write a d.ts file for this library.  How would I go about using this in a typescript file?

In a test.ts file, I tried doing a:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="libs/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js">
function newUser(){
    $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
    ... etc.
```

But webstorm reports an error on the "$" symbol as "unresolved method or function $()".  Tried replacing amd-dependency .. with reference.. but still did not work. The library path is correct. This code works fine if I put it in a .js file.

Comment: You could just write an inteface for the methods you need. Also, $ is part of jquery.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 is to include the declare file for jQuery. That will at least get you type info for vanilla jQuery. Put the following at the top of your JS files that are using jQuery

```
/// <reference path='jquery.d.ts' />
```

Next you will want to create a file jquery.easyui.d.ts and add this:

```
interface JQuery {
    dialog: any;
}
```

The code above means that the JQuery interface (initially defined in jquery.d.ts) has a member called dialog, and it can be of any type (in this case it's a function). Since you use `any`, you're not getting any type help for it, but at least it will now compile. I don't know what easyui adds to jQuery, but you will need to add all of the new methods to this interface.

And finally, add another `<reference>` comment below the first one for jquery.easyui.d.ts. Any time the compiler complains about something not being defined from easyui, add it to your jquery.easyui.d.ts file.

Once you get more proficient with the syntax, you can flesh out the types in your jquery.easyui.d.ts file and contribute them to the definitelytyped project!

Comment: Thanks ... it worked !  Like you said ... not getting intellisense code completion, but at least I can use that library like ordinary javascript.